# Layering JPanels with background image

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to have a background image and two panels atop them. Learnt that JLayeredpane's are quite suitable. So I extended a JLayeredPane in my class and tried to draw the image from paint(). I got it working. But when I added other layers over it they weren't visible.

Again I thought of removing the bgimage from LayeredPane, added to the first layer above it(in JPanel). Now the image is not visible. Why does it happen? I wanted to do some thing like the screenshot I've provided. Pls help.

My code:

From my JFrame:

```
Container cp = this.getContentPane();
JLayeredPane backDropPanel = new JLayeredPane();    
cp.add(backDropPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
backDropPanel.add(new bgPanel(), new Integer(1),0);
backDropPanel.add(new itemScrollerPanel(), new Integer(1),0);
```

Panel's:

```
class bgPanel extends JPanel{
String imageLocation = "/home/phantom/Desktop/BackDrop3.jpg";
private Image bgImage;
bgPanel(){
    bgImage = new ImageIcon(imageLocation).getImage();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,500));
    setLayout(null);
    setOpaque(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){      
super.paint(g);
g.drawImage(bgImage,0,0,this);
}}

class itemScrollerPanel extends JPanel{
    itemScrollerPanel(){
    setBounds(0,100,200,200);
    setBackground(Color.RED);
    setOpaque(true);

}}
```

In this code I get to see the itemsScrollerPanels's RED BG drawn. But not the image of bgPanel class.

My requirement is something like this:

[image]

Comment: +1 for an illustrative picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without setting your bgPanel size explicitly, I get

```
System.err.println(bgPanel.getSize());
//java.awt.Dimension[width=0,height=0]
```

If you change your code from

`setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));`

to

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
setSize(800,500);
```

You should see the panel painted.

Comment: if 1 is the problem how the second panel is visible? I haven't set it even. Tried 2 and didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the **setOpaque()** to false so that all the pixels of JPanel are not painted .Thus making it transparent.If you still cant do it,check whether the Jpanel is actually opaque or not using **isOpaque()**

Comment: setting opaque to false made the RED bg invisible. and both panels isOpaque returned true before I set that to false.